# Whited00r firmwares for 3GS and iPod touch 4G?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, jailbreak

Currently Whited00r has not released any firmwares for iPhone 3GS and iPod touch 4G , are they planning to release it in the near future?

Comment: How can we know? Did you check their site?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you don't get good answers, you can edit this to remove the speculation part about what someone/some group intends and simply explain in a little detail what you ultimately want to do and where your research has left you without an answer.

Comment: The same reason we don't have [Bootlace](http://lifehacker.com/5693309/how-to-install-android-on-an-iphone-in-six-easy-steps) past the iPhone 3GS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the whited00r project only supports the iPhone 2G, 3G, iPod 1, and iPod 2. The following is from the whited00r website.

> Whited00r is the biggest community of iOS modding and firmware cooking in the world. Here you will find full support for all Apple devices equipped with the ARMv6 CPU: 
>   iPhone 2G & 3G, iPod Touch 1G, 2G.

So as to why they didn't release it, there are several reasons.

1. The iPhone 3GS and the iPod 4 clearly don't run the ARMv6 CPU. They run the A4 chip (according to the specs, the iPhone 3GS has a ARMv8-Cortex, which is supposedly part of the A4 chip. Correct me if I'm wrong). The A4 chip is also on the iPhone 4, which shows that the devices are very capable, unlike the supported devices which can barely play new games.
2. The goal of the whited00r project is to bring new iOS features to old devices that cannot go past iOS 3/4. The iPhone 3GS and the iPod 4 can go up to iOS 6.1.6, which packs plenty of new features.
3. Whited00r is basically a new user interface. If you want your devices to look like iOS 7, jailbreak your device (http://posixspwndownload.com for iOS 6.1.3-6.1.5 and http://evasi0n.com for iOS 6.0 to 6.1.2) and grab Winterboard and a iOS 7 theme.

Sorry if this was a little harsh, but the whited00r team has reasons for not supporting them. If you want more info, I suggest contacting the team at legal@whited00r.com.